# Django is not displaying the image via /media/

Tags: python, django, image, url, media

Im stuck quite a while now I just can't display a picture a user has unloaded before. I have the option on my site to upload files and this part is working fine. I can see on the Admin Page via Posts that the image is there (name, title and tags)but when I try to view the image in admin or display it on the site I get an error. The Pictures are successfully added to my Media_cdn Folder in my project.

When I try to open it via admin page it says:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/scan.png
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
"/media/scan.png" does not exist
```

Also when I try to just open /Media/ it says page does not exist. when I want to open the Image on my website it gives me the symbols of a not found picture. but I can see the rest of the given information (Name,title,tags).

I hope somebody can tell me what part im missing.

Main settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media_cdn')
```

Main Urls.py

```
enter code here
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,     document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
```

urls.py for the view page

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my_profile/upload',views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^my_profile/mypost',views.mypost, name='mypost'),
    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:25],template_name='my_profile/my_profile.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model = Post ,template_name = 'my_profile/mypost.html' )),
    url(r'^my_profile/',views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

If anybody knows what to do please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set "document_root" as follows.

```
# Before.
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)

# After. change "document_root" from "MEDIA_URL" to "MEDIA_ROOT"
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I cannot believe I made this silly mistake. I can see it now in the Admin Page. You have a simple solution for the website view as well?
But again thanks a lot it feels like heaven seeing something something different than the error message haha

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer here

[Images from media folder is not displaying django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177208/images-from-media-folder-is-not-displaying-django-template/68325385#68325385)